# C++ format using raw string literals

Tags: c++, string, format, c++23

Can you use C++20 format() with raw string literals ? error message return by gcc 14.

```
#include <format>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int id=6, sigma_edge_distance=9, width=6, height=9, total=6;
    string buffer = format(R"({"id":{}, "sigma_edge_distance":{}, "width":{}, "height":{}, "total":{}})",
                id, sigma_edge_distance, width, height, total);
    printf("%s", buffer.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

error:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:9:27: error: call to consteval function 'std::basic_format_string<char, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&>("{\"id\":{}, \"sigma_edge_distance\":{}, \"width\":{}, \"height\":{}, \"total\":{}}")' is not a constant expression
    9 |     string buffer = format(R"({"id":{}, "sigma_edge_distance":{}, "width":{}, "height":{}, "total":{}})",
      |                     ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   10 |                                 id, sigma_edge_distance, width, height, total);
      |                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from prog.cc:1:
prog.cc:9:27:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'std::basic_format_string<char, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&>("{\"id\":{}, \"sigma_edge_distance\":{}, \"width\":{}, \"height\":{}, \"total\":{}}")'
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/14.0.1/format:4175:19:   in 'constexpr' expansion of '__scanner.std::__format::_Checking_scanner<char, int, int, int, int, int>::std::__format::_Scanner<char>.std::__format::_Scanner<char>::_M_scan()'
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/14.0.1/format:3917:30:   in 'constexpr' expansion of '((std::__format::_Scanner<char>*)this)->std::__format::_Scanner<char>::_M_on_replacement_field()'
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/14.0.1/format:3960:58: error: call to non-'constexpr' function 'void std::__format::__invalid_arg_id_in_format_string()'
 3960 |               __format::__invalid_arg_id_in_format_string();
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/14.0.1/format:218:3: note: 'void std::__format::__invalid_arg_id_in_format_string()' declared here
  218 |   __invalid_arg_id_in_format_string()
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Minor: stdio.h -> cstdio

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/9Kehvahqd - made some changes, works!

Comment: it does compile without issues if I remove the curly braces at the beginning and at the end. So it was an issue with the compilation of the raw string literals itself. Nothing to do with format().

Comment: Quite the opposite, this has nothing to do with the literal being raw and everything to do with `format`. You need to double up literal curly braces you want to print with `format`, so use `"{{....}}"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use double braces like `{{ .. }}` in order to use braces inside the format string.

```
#include <format>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int id=6, sigma_edge_distance=9, width=6, height=9, total=6;
    string buffer = format(R"({{ "id": {}, "sigma_edge_distance": {}, "width": {}, "height": {}, "total": {} }})",
                id, sigma_edge_distance, width, height, total);
    printf("%s", buffer.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```